# Mysql Many to Many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm, many-to-many

I am trying to implement a simple many to many relationship between two tables. 
User and Groups.

```
User
---------
user_id
user_name

Group
----------
group_id
group_name

UserGroup
----------
user_id
group_id
```

Lets say both the user and group table each has 1000 entries.

I have to create one admin user that belongs to all groups.
Should I create 1000 entries in the UserGroup table for the "admin" user?

Can I create a boolean column say "Applicable_to_all_groups" in User table that should be checked first before selecting from UserGroup table?

Any suggestion on doing this the correct way will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a hard coded group called `ADMIN` and associate the admin user this group.

Comment: We use an "Apply to all" setting rather than joining every user when we want ALL users to belong to a certain group. The benefit here is that new users belong to that group without specifically having to add them.

Comment: if it has to be all combinations you can look into a cartesian product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say there's no "true" solution for that kind of cases.

Let's look on some pros / cons

**Solution 1**, all in UserGroup table

*Pros*

Requests to get allowed groups is easier to write (no OR clause)

*Cons*

You will have to add an entry in this table every time you add an entry in the group table.
Doable, of course, but boring, and error-prone.

If you want a new User "which can also be related to all groups", you'll have to rewrite all your procedures / triggers / whatever you use to have "up-to-date" UserGroup table to add this new thing.

**Solution2**, flag (= boolean column)

*Pros*

Avoid unnecessary entries in your db (well, minor point)

Always "up-to-date", without any additional work.

Easy to add a new User with "all groups" rights (just put the flag to true)

*Cons*

You'll have to add OR clauses when requesting for allowed groups (based on flag or on GroupUser 
table)

**A personal point of view**

I would go for the flag solution...